# wrap a function as a method in a subclass of a class in python

Tags: python, class, wrapper, python-decorators, functools

here is the (simplified) case :

I have a class containing a subclass :

```
>>> inst = Foo()
>>> inst.sub.bar()
```

it returns something magnificent from the bar() method of the subclass.
this is written like :

```
class Sub() :
    def __init__(inst) :
        self.inst = inst

    def bar(self) :
        '''does something magnificent  with the Foo instance (self.inst)'''
        return smtg

class Foo() :
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sub = Sub(self)
```

when using Foo in a third class for specific stuff :

```
class superFoo(Foo) :
    
    def specific(self,*a,**kw) :
        ...
```

I would also like to wrap specific methods in the subclass using a @decorator, the way I would do for Foo :

```
from functools import wraps

def add_method(cls):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func) 
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, func.__name__, wrapper)
    return decorator
    
@add_method(superFoo)
def spam(self, *args, **kwargs) :
    return self.specific() + ...
    
>>> inst = superFoo()
>>> inst.spam() # yep
```

but what I want is this :

```
>>> inst.sub.spam()
```

so I tried :

```
@add_method(superFoo)
def spam(self, *args, **kwargs) :
    return self.inst.specific() + ...
```

and in the add_method function :

```
setattr(cls.sub, func.__name__, wrapper) # ouch, sub not instantiated
```

fail.

I can sublass Sub (actually I did this for now) to answer the need :

```
class superSub(Sub) :
    def spam(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        return self.inst.specific() + ...

class superFoo(Foo) :
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs) # there is actualy other inheritances 
        self.sub = superSub(self) # replaces Sub() by its subclass
```

but I wonder if I could use a decorator, if this is possible, to do so :
`add_method` would be imported in a module when needed,  and the specific stuff would of the module would appear at first sight when reviewing the code :

```
from abyssal import add_method

class superFoo(Foo) : # folded in my editor

@add_method(superFoo) :
def spam(self) : # folded
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your usage of a decorator is not the way they are meant to be used (not saying it is wrong, it's just counterintuitive). It should change the function that it decorates, not its parameter with the function. Could you please include more details on, why you are doing this. It seems that there should be a better approach.

Comment: the Sub() class is used in dozens of Foo() subclasses in a django project and answers the need for most of them. For one corner case I need to add and override some Sub() method, and would like to find other ways than inheritance/__init__/setattr.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_method` decorator could be a method of your `superFoo` class:

```
class superFoo(Foo):

    def add_method(self):
        def decorator(func):
            setattr(self, func.__name__, func)
            return func
        return decorator
```

(note I simplified it a bit)

Then you'll use it as:

```
sub = Sub()
inst = superFoo(sub)

@inst.add_method(superFoo)
def spam(self, *args, **kwargs) :
    return self.inst.specific() + ...
```

But again. I'd suggest using the inheritance. Just defining sub-class for `Sub` would be much simpler and more understandable.

Comment: I agree there's no added value to define ``add_method`` as a ``superFoo`` method, and that it's better to use __init__ to override ``self.sub`` by a subclass (I edited my question to mention this way).

Answer (score 0):

Dude, what do you want is to make inst.sub.spam() works, right? spam() has to use inst attribute to work. I assume got you correctly.
Try the following code.

```
class Foo:

    class Sub:
        def __init__(self, object) -> None:
            self.object = object
            
        def spam(self):
            print('I print a Foo attribute')
            print('Foo attribute is:', self.object.name)
        
        
def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'foo'
    self.sub = Foo.Sub(self)

    
inst = Foo()  
inst.sub.spam()
```